# Passing Parameter in URL search

Tags: javascript, search, parameter-passing

I am in the process of creating a search functionality. Please see [UI example](http://codepen.io/leetech/pen/OVvMKE/). The following is my HTML

```
  <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
      </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search</button>
    <a class="btn" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span> Filter
  </a>
  </form>
```

When the search button is clicked, whatever term has been entered needs to be passed in URL via a JS script in order to go to another page and display results.

Any help would be appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `action` and `method` attributes to the `form` tag. And the `name` attribute to the `input` tag.

This will go to the URL: `search.php?term=value`

```
<form action="search.php" method="GET" class="navbar-form" role="search">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="term" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-anz"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search</button>
    <a class="btn btn-anz" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span> Filter
    </a>
</form>
```

Comment: Great thank you....so all I need to do is replace the "search.php" with my results page URL. In regards to the JS something like [JS Code](http://javascriptproductivity.blogspot.com.au/2013/02/get-url-variables-with-javascript.html) would be sufficient?

Comment: I'm not great at vanilla JS but it looks OK. If you think one of the answers helped you with your solution, please accept it as your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yo have to add method and action attributes to the from tag.

Like this-

```
<form action="search.php" method="GET" class="navbar-form" role="search">
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="item" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-anz"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search</button>
<a class="btn btn-anz" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span> Filter
</a>
```

then using javascriupt you can use appropriate techinique to retrieve the value and process the search results.